# Prove that the sum of a sequence of real numbers converges if and only if..

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is what I am trying to prove:  Let $ (a_k) $ be a sequence of real numbers. Prove that $ \sum(a_k) $ converges if and only if for any $ \epsilon > 0 $, there is a natural number N so that if $ n  \geq N $, then $$\left|{}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k\right|<\epsilon $$

I know that a sequence $a_n$ is said to converge to a real number if for every  $\epsilon>0$,
there is a natural number N such that if n ≥ N,
then $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$.

I need to prove the sum. Can you help?

Comment: Whild you're at it, make sure to remove the Number-theory tag aswell

Comment: Your statement of what you are trying to prove looks circular to me: in order for the condition $|\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k| < \varepsilon$ to make sense, you have to assume the convergence of $\sum a_k$. Where did you get this problem?

Comment: I agree. It is more of a definition, but I have to provide a proof for it.

Comment: This is a BAD characterization because $$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k$$ simply does not exist unless $\sum\limits_ka_k$ converges.

Answer (score 2):

You can 'prove' this definition formally by considering the sequence obtained by taking the partial sums and resorting to the formal definition of the limit of a sequence (because we have to start somewhere). That is

Consider the sequence $s_n := \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ of partial sums. That $s_n$ converges is equivalent to the convergence of your series (whose limit is $L = \sum_{i>0} a_i$). So for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N$  such that $|s_n - L|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. Substituting the appropriate values for $s_n$ and $L$ reveals $$\left|\sum_{i>n} a_i\right| <\left|\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty a_i\right|  = \left|\sum_{i>0}a_i - \sum_{i=1}^na_i \right| = |L-s_n|<\epsilon.$$